# How to make Oracle Data Integrator ETL process monitor in OBI

Tags: oracle, plsql, etl, business-intelligence, oracle-data-integrator

I have some ETL processes in Oracle Data Integrator 11, so I need to make a report in BI about these processes, I need to export the following information from ODI (into BI):

1. Date of data loading
2. Name of report (e.g. rep1, rep2, rep3) = name of interface in ODI
3. Time of loading
4. Result - OK/ERROR

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite easy

we need to create a table as following

```
create table view_sessions as (SELECT
    sess_no,
    sess_name,
    sess_status,
    SCEN_NAME, 
    TO_CHAR(SESS_BEG,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as "Session_Start",
    TO_CHAR(SESS_END,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as "Session_End",
    SESS_DUR
FROM SNP_SESSION);
```

then build  new repository in OBI Administration tool(based on that table)

and after all create requested report in OBI

Answer (score 0):

You have three tables to get all the information.

SNP_SESSION

SNP_SESS_STEP

SNP_SESS_TASK

These tables will be available only in odi repository.

All these tables are connected with SESS_NO. You can easily query.

SESS_STATUS column will tell you the OK/ERROR.

There are others useful  columns there like sess_sur, sess_beg, sess_end, nb_ins etc.